# Post multiple checkbox data of Datatable checkbox on button click on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable, datatables

This is the datatable script that creates the datatable. Checkbox target is 0, so the first column of each row is always a checkbox. That checkbox inherits an {{id}} that was sent via django views.

I want to somehow send those ids back via URL to a view, so i can see the student Ids I have seleced in datatable.

It would be really great if someone knows how to get this done in Javascript. The Ids are currently printed-> console.log(PostData) when the button is clicked. Help much apprecciated!:)

table_html:

```
<div  width="100%">
    <form action="" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="table_id2" width="100%" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Add</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>surname</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>location</th>
                <th>address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    
    
        <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ student.ID}}</th>
                <th>{{ student.title }}</th>
                <th>{{ student.name }}</th>
                <th>{{ student.surname }}</th>
                <th>{{ student.email }}</th>
                <th>{{ student.location }}</th>
                <th>{{ student.address }}</th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
{% block js %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.12/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
     <script>
         var PostData;
        $(document).ready( function () {
        var table = $('#table_id2').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{% url 'table_list_addStudents' %}",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
        }
            } ],
            select: {
                style:    'multi',
            },
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
 
            
        });
        var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
            buttons: [
            {
                    text: 'Add Students',
                    action: function () {
        
                var data = table.rows( { selected: true } ).data().pluck(0).toArray();
               
                if(data.length > 0){
                    PostData = data
                    console.log(PostData)
                 }  
         }
            },
        ]
        }).container().appendTo('#buttons')

        
        });
        
        
        
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: If someone knows a diffenrent approach on how to somehow get the ids that are checked in checkbox without javascript would be also totally good, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax and Django in combination need a done.function() about success or not. This is just a test code that worked fine. data is always succsess as you can see in the views.py

```
            var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
            buttons: [
            {
                    text: 'Add Students',
                    action: function () {
        
                var data = table.rows( { selected: true } ).data().pluck(0).toArray();
               
                if(data.length > 0){
                    
                    data = JSON.stringify(data)
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "",
                    data: {

                        'Data' : data,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    }).done(function(data){
                        if (data.success){
                            window.location.href = "{% url 'Kurs-page' %}";
                        }
                    });
                 }  
         }
            },
        ]
        }).container().appendTo('#buttons')


if request.is_ajax():
#doStuff
return JsonResponse({
            'success':True
    }) #this is going to be returned to ".done " function in js.
```

It works for me. If someone wants to improve it, would be cool. For my part I solved the issue and just wanted to post it, so other guys can see how to handle it in django.